# console.log Reddit "Saves" data on scroll

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, request, reddit

I want to save the JSON data of things I save on Reddit as I scroll. I have previously used the following code successfully to hook into any fetch requests, check if the URL contained a specific string, and then execute a function passing in the data:

```js
const {fetch: origFetch} = window;
window.fetch = async (...args) => {
    const response = await origFetch(...args);
    if($(response)[0].url.includes("keyword")){
        response.clone().json().then(body =>modifyDOM(body)).catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
    return response;
};
```

However, this code does not appear to work when I use it on Reddit. What am I missing?